# How to fix Error 14 -- Unable to open ~/.qgis//qgis.db?

Tags: qgis

I get this error:

```
Error 14 -- Unable to open ~/.qgis//qgis.db -- QGIS version 1.8.0-Lisboa -- Ubuntu 12.04
```

I had define a custom CRS and that error occurred when I tried to save that CRS under "settings"→"custom CRS" in QGIS 1.80.0-Lisboa on Ubuntu 12.04.

I notice that the `qgis.db` file is located at:

```
/usr/share/qgis/resources/qgis.db
```

I created a link but this did not work either. Can I tell QGIS to look for the qgis database at the above location rather that `~/.qgis//`? Looks like permissions are read and write for all users.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove/rename `qgis.db` from/in `~/.qgis`.  If will be recreated automatically.  The problem probably is that the format of the `tbl_srs` table meanwhile changed.

If you hit more problems, it might be a good idea to remove/rename the `~/.qgis` directory and perhaps also `~/.config/QuantumGIS`.

Beware: that will remove the old user settings, but those are probably incompatible between 1.8 and whatever you had before.

Answer (score 1):

I suffer the same problem, but I found another solution. First, the file is in `/home/vyg/.qgis` and, after trying the solution above, and even change (just for trying) my distro from Ubuntu 12.04 Precise to Linux Mint 13 (64bit), and finally to Linux Mint 13-32bit, I realize that there was a lock in the file, that indicates limited permissions. So, I simply change them with the following sequence of command-line commands

```
YOUR_USER ~ $ cd /home/MICARPETAPERSONAL
YOUR_USER ~ $ sudo chmod 777 .qgis
```

and Listo!!! va en Español mexicano

¡Hola! Padecí el mismo problema, pero encontré otra solución. Primero, el archivo lo encontré en otra ruta `/home/MICARPETAPERSONAL/.qgis`, tras probar la solución que ofrecen arriba,e incluso cambiar de distro de Ubuntu 12.04 Precise, a Linux Mint 13 (64bit), y finalmente a Linux Mint 13-32bit, me dí cuenta de que la carpeta tenía un candado, lo que indica permisos limitados. Así que simplemente los cambié con la siguiente secuencia de códigos:

```
YOUR_USER ~ $ cd /home/vyg
YOUR_USER ~ $ sudo chmod 777 .qgis
```

y Listo, a trabajar :-)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mess up the uids while switching distributions?  Sounds like the user didn't own his .qgis directory (probably his whole home directory).  Did you check the actual permissions (ls -ld .qgis)?

Comment: No,that was not the case. And it was commpletly solved after the premissions were changed :-)